# Java: Fixing array "linking" to allow for resetting

Tags: java, arrays, final

Firstly, I know Lists are better in almost(if not all) every way. I have encountered a substantial bug in an encoder program that I am making. In this program, I have a button that resets the "wheels" responsible for encoding(One of the wheels rotates after every letter encoded). I have a final int[][] called wheelsOriginal that is supposed to store the original value of the int[][] called wheels. Both of these arrays are int[9][36]. I would like a way of making wheelsOriginal stay unchanged throughout the program instead of changing with wheels for some reason. Here is a good way to recreate the problem(Sorry for the lengthy intToChar and charToInt methods!):

Main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Encoder");
        frame.setBackground(new Color(225,225,225));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Display d = new Display();
        frame.add(d);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Display class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Display extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static JButton button;
    static JLabel letter;
    static int currentKey = -10;
    static int wheel = 0;
    static int[][] wheels = {
        {-3,10,-6,2,20,-7,22,5,23,4,6,-9,3,26,0,15,21,-2,13,14,12,1,17,11,-8,-5,18,8,24,9,25,7,19,16,-4,-1},
        {9,22,14,12,18,-3,3,6,16,1,-7,25,24,19,-8,8,21,20,5,-6,-2,26,15,-9,23,10,11,0,-5,4,-4,2,17,-1,13,7},
        {18,20,-9,15,12,-6,16,-4,-5,14,24,-7,-8,-3,-1,1,4,7,8,25,10,11,5,6,13,22,19,21,23,-2,3,26,17,9,0,2},
        {-3,10,-6,2,20,-7,22,5,23,4,6,-9,3,26,0,15,21,-2,13,14,12,1,17,11,-8,-5,18,8,24,9,25,7,19,16,-4,-1},
        {9,22,14,12,18,-3,3,6,16,1,-7,25,24,19,-8,8,21,20,5,-6,-2,26,15,-9,23,10,11,0,-5,4,-4,2,17,-1,13,7},
        {25,18,5,8,7,-8,4,11,6,-7,26,21,-1,24,15,23,9,-6,-2,13,16,22,-5,10,17,3,1,-9,0,12,2,19,-4,14,20,-3},
        {25,18,5,8,7,-8,4,11,6,-7,26,21,-1,24,15,23,9,-6,-2,13,16,22,-5,10,17,3,1,-9,0,12,2,19,-4,14,20,-3},
        {25,18,5,8,7,-8,4,11,6,-7,26,21,-1,24,15,23,9,-6,-2,13,16,22,-5,10,17,3,1,-9,0,12,2,19,-4,14,20,-3},
        {9,22,14,12,18,-3,3,6,16,1,-7,25,24,19,-8,8,21,20,5,-6,-2,26,15,-9,23,10,11,0,-5,4,-4,2,17,-1,13,7}
    };
    final static int[][] wheelsOriginal = wheels;

    public Display() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,200));
        setFocusable(true);
        button = new JButton("Reset");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(225,50));
        button.setFont(new Font(button.getFont().getFontName(), button.getFont().getStyle(), 25));
        letter = new JLabel(" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        letter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(225,100));
        letter.setFont(new Font(letter.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, 125));
        letter.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        addKeyListener(
            new KeyListener() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(currentKey == -10 && e.getKeyCode() >= 65 && e.getKeyCode() <= 90) {
                        currentKey = e.getKeyCode() - 64;
                        letter.setText(encode() + "");
                    }
                    else if(currentKey == -10 && e.getKeyCode() >= 48 && e.getKeyCode() <= 57) {
                        currentKey = -1 * (e.getKeyCode() - 48);
                        letter.setText(encode() + "");
                    }
                }
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    currentKey = -10;
                    letter.setText(" ");
                }
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            }
        );
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button, TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        add(letter);
    }

    public static char encode() {
        int key = currentKey;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            key = wheels[i][key + 9];
        }
        for(int i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
            key = wheels[i][key + 9];
        }
        rotate(wheels[wheel], isEven(wheel));
        if(wheel < 8) {
            wheel++;
        }
        else {
            wheel = 0;
        }
        return((char) key);
    }

    public static int[] rotate(int[] wheel, boolean positive) {
        int revolve;
        if(positive) {
            revolve = wheel[wheel.length - 1];
            for(int i = wheel.length - 2; i > 0; i--) {
                wheel[i + 1] = wheel[i];
            }
            wheel[0] = revolve;
        }
        else {
            revolve = wheel[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < wheel.length - 1; i++) {
                wheel[i - 1] = wheel[i];
            }
            wheel[wheel.length - 1] = revolve;
        }

        return wheel;
    }

    public static boolean isEven(int num) {
        return (num/2 == Math.abs(num/2));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(button)) {
            reset();
            grabFocus();
        }
    }

    public static void reset() {
        for(int[] i : wheels) {
            for(int x : i) {
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int[] i : wheelsOriginal) {
            for(int x : i) {
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        wheels = wheelsOriginal;
        for(int[] i : wheels) {
            for(int x : i) {
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        wheel = 0;
        letter.setText(" ");
        currentKey = ' ';
        System.out.println("Pressed");
    }
}
```

Whenever a key is pressed, the encoded letter appears in the window. Even pressing the same key over and over again will usually produce different letters. Pressing the reset button should reset the encoder so that pressing the letter 'A' three times should produce S, E, and Q in that order. I also have designed this so that whenever you press the reset button, three large bulks of numbers print in the console. These show the wheels array before reset, the wheelsOriginal array, and the product wheels array in that order. If you press keys and click reset several times, you will notice that wheelsOriginal changes with wheels. Please help...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: So dumping your code here and yelling help is not really useful to any future reader, also it is currently highly unclear what your problem is. So please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Lino I minimized the code a lot. The intended behavior is that wheelsOriginal never changes value so that when reset() is called the value of wheels can be set to wheelsOriginal...I thought that was fairly clear. I am really at a loss as to how to minimize the code in a way that debugging would actually help me. My problem is clearly stated that wheelsOriginal is changing when it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Lino If you have any suggestions for clarifying the question somehow or shortening the code, I would be glad to fix my question. I just don't know how to do that. Probably because of the massive headache I got while trying to understand why this happens and what might fix it.

Comment: currently you have pasted 373 lines of code, if you've read the [mcve] then you should understand that this is **not** a minimal complete verfiable example. You should try to debug your code. Observing what happens to `wheelsOriginal` when pressing a button and so on

Comment: @Lino, the problem isn't with the button. This is why I included those console outputs in the reset method code. Also, to be fair, the majority of the code are just the stupid intToChar and charToInt methods. I will go and shorten those now.

Comment: I said *and so on*, you have to debug every action you make to fully understand what may not be working

Comment: @Lino I think you just don't get it. I pinpointed the bug, it was that wheelsOriginal was moving with wheels inside of the rotate method. I just didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have a look at the answer below. That will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating wheelsOriginal as reference of wheels instead of copy. Thats why when you change wheels, wheelsOriginal changes as well.

```
final static int[][] wheelsOriginal = wheels;
```

Something like this loop can be used to create a copy of wheels

```
int[][] wheelsOriginal = new int[wheels.length][];
for( int i = 0; i < wheelsOriginal.length; i++ )
{
    wheelsOriginal[i] = Arrays.copyOf( wheels[i], wheels[i].length );
}
```

Also, for your `charToInt` and `IntToChar` methods - you could use the fact that chars are numbers and a->z A->Z 0->9 are grouped together to shorten them significantly

I didn't test that - in case you decide to use something like this - think and test yourself

```
public int charToInt( char c )
{
    if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) {
        return '0' - c;
    } else if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) {
        return c - 'A' + 1;
    } else if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) {
        return c - 'a' + 1;
    } else {
        return -10;
    }
}

public char intToChar( int c )
{
    if( c >= -9 && c <= 0 ){
        return (char)('0' - c);
    } else if( c >= 1 && c <= 26 ){
        return (char)(c + 'A' - 1);
    } else{
        return ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it? From what I remember Arrays.copyOf - makes a brand new "outer" array, but copies references for "inner" arrays in case of 2d arrays. In that case adding a loop will provide a fix for that.

Comment: @Lino Would I have to do the Arrays.copyOf thing to each of the nine arrays of 36 integers individually?

Comment: @Bug `wheelsOriginal = Arrays.copyOf(wheels, wheels.length); for(int i = 0; i < wheels.length; i++){wheelsOriginal[i] = Arrays.copyOf(wheels[i], wheels[i].length);}`

Comment: @Lino Yeah, that's what I thought. I just didn't do the for loop.

Comment: I added some content out there, also mentioned intToChar and charToInt

Comment: @Worthless The intToChar and charToInt thing is interesting. I do use chars and ints sometimes but this is great, thanks!

Comment: The wheel for loop should also be used with wheels and wheelsOriginal reversed in the reset method btw.